# Are humans indigenous to the world of Camorr, Tal Verarr and the Ghostwind Islands?

Tags: scott-lynch, gentlemen-bastards

In the world of [Scott Lynch's *Gentlemen Bastard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gentleman_Bastard_Sequence) series ([*The Lies of Locke Lamora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lies_of_Locke_Lamora), [*Red Seas Under Red Skies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Seas_Under_Red_Skies) and [*The Republic of Thieves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Republic_of_Thieves)), the human subjects of the books exist in a world filled with large "elderglass" buildings and edifices from an ancient and seemingly no longer extant race called the "eldren." The descriptions of elderglass and the eldren make plain that their civilization spanned the planet, and that the humans have nowhere near the technological and/or magical sophistication of the vanished race.

Is there any indication that the humans of this world are indigenous to it, or that they perhaps arrived there from elsewhere?